# Address of pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Looking at the following Code:

```c
char* c = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*BUF);
```

I know that doing

```
printf("%c\n", *c);
```

gives me the first character in the string. Also,

```
printf("%s\n", c);
```

prints the whole string, where c is the address of the first character.
However, what is the meaning of &c? Is it the address of the address? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `&c` is the address of the variable `c`

Comment: There are 1000s post on StackOverflow related to this. Please do some search

Comment: "*the whole string*" There is no (C-)string in the code you show.

Comment: It's much more **faster** to do a search than writing a post.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", c);` Will invoke undefined behaviour if c is not null terminated.

Comment: @George: even more (or better "less" ;-), the memory is not initialised at all.

Comment: Yup, also while it probably won't cause an issue here, [casting the result of _malloc_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), can mask errors/warnings.

Answer (score 2):

`&c` is the adress of your variable `c` (which itself contains the adress of your allocated array).